# One workstation not able to communicate with one server via hostname

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-dns

I have one computer that cannot access shares via hostname. I can ping the hostname and it resolves to the FQDN fine. I can access the shares via FQDN and IP. However, when I change the map network drive and a shortcut to a network app to use the FQDN, and I reboot, it no longer works with FQDN but with just the hostname. I then change it back, reboot and the same thing happens again. I ensured that the dns suffix is in the IP settings, and other servers work just fine only using the hostname. No other computer is having this issue on the network.

UPDATE:
Everything is configured properly. I just had another user complain about this. After some more looking into this... Turns out this is happening with all the computers of the same model. Dell Optiplex 7040. Saw that the driver was from 2015. Updated to the latest driver. This did not appear to fix the issue. This is only happening with one of the servers. Also this is the only server on the network that uses SMB 1.0. I do have SMB client 1.0 installed on the workstation.

UPDATE 2: It appears to be one specific network drive causing the issue. If I don't mount that drive, the other network drive to that same server works. We usually use a mintty script to mount the drive. I am tried manually mounting the W: drive and the same thing happens.

UPDATE 3: The hostname resolves just fine when I do nslookup. Also, If I mount \serverA.domain.com\share1 to W: and \serverA\share2 to V:, after a reboot, W: won't work, but V: does. If I mount \serverA\share1 to W: and \serverA\share2 to V:, none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that no other computer in your network is having the stated issue, it seems, the problem lies with DNS client settings for your computer rather than DNS server settings.

Please verify that TCP/IP configuration settings for your computer are correct, particularly those used for DNS name resolution.

To verify a client IP configuration, use the ipconfig command. In the command output, verify that the client has a valid IP address, subnet mask, and default gateway for the network where it is attached and being used.

If your machine does not have a valid TCP/IP configuration, you can either:

1. Use the ipconfig /renew command to manually force the client to renew its IP address configuration with the DHCP server.
2. Modify the client TCP/IP properties to use valid configuration settings or complete its DNS configuration for the network.

Please refer to the following links for detailed instructions on DNS client configuration and TCP/IP configuration  -

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc778792(v=ws.10)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc783907(v=ws.10)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc757052(v=ws.10)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is  the configuration of Dell Optiplex 7040 thru your network drive. Did you try accessing the drive via \networkdriveip?

i had one problem with other computers in my office. i had reformatted the client pc so it can communicate to the server

Comment: I even had a computer of the same model that we decided to throw an SSD in and so we did a complete reinstall from scratch, and it's the same issue. I'd rather not use IP's, just to keep things the same across the board, but I can give that a try to see if we have any issues with the network drive.

Comment: I tried doing this with IP just now and when you reboot, same issue. The drive doesn't work. and can't even \\ipaddress in file explorer.